# How to prove that $u(\epsilon') = \inf\{f(s) - f(s+\epsilon'): s \in [0,t]\} > 0$ for strictly decreasing function $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, supremum-and-infimum, epsilon-delta

Let $f$ be a monotone strictly decreasing function. Fix $\epsilon' > 0$. How to prove that $u(\epsilon') = \inf\{f(s) - f(s+\epsilon'): s \in [0,t]\} > 0$ ?

Comment: What does $$u$$ mean?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly,
$$
f(s)-f(s+\varepsilon')>0,
$$
for all $\,s\in [0,t]$ and $\varepsilon'>0$. Hence
$$
\inf\{f(s)-f(s+\varepsilon'): s\in [0,t]\}\ge 0.
$$
Assume that for some $\varepsilon'>0$, $\inf\{f(s)-f(s+\varepsilon'): s\in [0,t]\}= 0$.

This implies that for every $n\in\mathbb N$, there exists an $s_n\in[0,t]$, such that
$$
0<f(s_n)-f(s_n+\varepsilon')<\frac{1}{n} \tag{1}
$$
The sequence $\{s_n\}\subset [0,t]$ possesses a convergent subsequence, say $s_{k_n}\to s\in [0,t]$. The $\{s_n\}$ can be chosen to be monotone.

Case I. $\{s_n\}$ decreasing.

Then $s_n\to s^+$ and $f(s_n)\to \lim_{\sigma\to s^+}f(\sigma)$, while
$s_n+\varepsilon'\to s^+$ and $f(s_n)\to \lim_{\sigma\to (s+\varepsilon')^+}f(\sigma)$,
and according to $(1)$,
$$
\lim_{\sigma\to s^+}f(\sigma)=\lim_{\sigma\to (s+\varepsilon')^+}f(\sigma)
\tag{2}
$$
However, if $s<x<s+\varepsilon'$, then for large enough $n$,
$$
s_n<x<s_n+\varepsilon'
$$
which implies that
$$
f(s_n)>f(x)>f(s_n+\varepsilon') 
$$
and hence
$$
\lim_{\sigma\to s^+}f(\sigma)>f(x)\ge \lim_{\sigma\to (s+\varepsilon')^+}f(\sigma)
$$
This contradicts $(2)$.

Case II. $\{s_n\}$ increasing. Treated similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Question has some implied assumptions!

Notice that $ s \to f(s) - f(s+\epsilon') $ is a continuous function that is positive at every $s$. Therefore, it has a minimum on the compact interval $[0,t]$. Now the proof finishes with
$$
\inf\{f(s) - f(s+\epsilon'): s \in [0,t]\} = \min_{0\leq s \leq t} u(s) > 0 \, .
$$

Comment: We only know that $f$ is strictly decreasing, how can you say $s \mapsto \cdots$ is continuous?